# How to create objects in Dojo

Tags: dojo

How to create objects in Dojo ? How to inherit that objects in Dojo ( for example: I want to create class A with field a and method ACK, then create class B and C, B inherits A and B inherits C ) ? How to do that ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you look for is the method `dojo.declare(className, extends, fields)`:

Create class A with field a and method ACK:

```
dojo.declare("com.mycompany.myapp.A", null, {
    a: "myValue", // field

    ACK: function(param) { // method
       // do something
    }
});
```

After that declaration you can instantiate objects of your new class:

```
var x = new com.mycompany.myapp.A();
x.ACK(1);
alert(x.a);
```

If you don't like to use the full namespace and want more Java-like declarations:

```
var A = com.mycompany.myapp.A;
var x = new A();
```

Create class B and C, B inherits A and B inherits C:

```
dojo.declare("com.mycompany.myapp.C", null, {  
    // field list
});

dojo.declare("com.mycompany.myapp.B", 
             [com.mycompany.myapp.A, com.mycompany.myapp.C], // B inherits from A and C                  
{  
    // field list
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You should definitely have a good look at the extensive documentation for `dojo.declare`:

http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/dojo/declare.html

Also potentially of interest, but certainly not to be confused with the above, are [`dojo.mixin`](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/dojo/mixin.html) and [`dojo.extend`](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/dojo/extend.html).